# Why is my complex [FromBody] parameter null?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am having trouble with the `[FromBody]` parameter of my method not binding.

example C#:

```
[Route("api/path")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] ComplexType param)
{
    // param is null
}
public class ComplexType
{
    public string name { get; set;}
}
```

I've checked the POST body content and content-type and it looks correct.

Why is it null despite throughly checking that the data being posted and content type all match what is expected?

N.B. This is a deliberatly vague question since I was having a lot of trouble diagnosing an issue and I couldn't find a suitable question and answer.
When I eventually found the problem I kicked myself for it, but I feel the need to share *how* I found the problem to hopefully spare others the pain.

As it happens there may well be nothing wrong with the example given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case there was a problem with the definition of the complex type, I had a parameter marked as `string` while it should have been `string[]` and so the JSON parsed did not match the model.

The important part though is how I found this out:

When debugging any API method there is the magic `ModelState` property.
This property gives you information about any failures that occur while binding the data received to the expected parameters.

e.g:
[image]

here we can see the parameter (`uploaded`), and the property within that parameter which failed to bind correctly.

Check the definition of that property and you'll probably find an error.